# How to update to latest version of Parse-SDK-JS after parse migration of cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Compatibility-with-Hosted-Parse#Cloud-Code

"Minimum JavaScript SDK version

Parse Server also uses at least version 1.7.0 of the Parse SDK, which has some breaking changes from the previous versions. If your Parse.com Cloud Code uses a previous version of the SDK, you may need to update your cloud code. You can look up which version of the JavaScript SDK your Parse.com Cloud Code is using by running the following command inside your Cloud Code folder:

$ parse jssdk
Current JavaScript SDK version is 1.7.0"

---

my Current JavaScript SDK version is 1.6.14

the latest Parse javascript JDK is at

### https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/releases/tag/v1.8.5

how do I actually use the download to update to that version of the Parse-SDK-JS??

Comment: you are running parse jssdk command on a parse.com project and not parse-server project right  ?

Comment: yes apologies, this was a stupid question it seems

Comment: it's not stupid question at all.. do you want to know how you can change the parse js sdk in parse-server?

Comment: Yes if that's required? right now i'm getting this error in heroku logs ; ReferenceError: Parse is not defined

Comment: Where you get this error in cloud code?

Comment: /app/cloud/main.js:6

    Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {

    ^

Answer (score 0):

fixed my migration issues by starting again from scratch